# Does stimulated emission also occur under the weak force?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, weak-interaction, electroweak

Q: is stimulated emission only relevant for electromagnetic interactions through photons, or is it also valid for beta-decay?
Example: Imagine an amount of tritium decaying in a strong beam of anti-electron neutrinos, would the pattern of electron emission then be non-spherical? I realise any effect would be negligable, but is there an a-priori reason why the Standard Model would say "no"?

Comment: actually stimulated emission works on excited states of bound states, atomic and molecular, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stimulated_emission  I know of no bound states with the weak interaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For photons, stimulated emission arises as a result of their bosonic nature and an affinity for two photons to share the same quantum state (e.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/65717/43351).

The anti-neutrinos are fermions, so if you "illuminated" the tritium with a strong enough beam you would have something like the *opposite* of stimulated emission. The Pauli Exclusion Principle would forbid the presence of two anti-neutrinos in the same quantum state.